# ERROR: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3696: character maps to <undefined> (Windows Command Line, bokeh program)

Tags: python, utf-8, bokeh

I've been trying to run something similar to the gapminder program in Bokeh. I'm reasonably sure my code for the plots is fine, so I won't post it, and I'm about 70% sure my code for the plot update is also fine. However, when I run

```
bokeh serve --show myapp.py
```

in my Windows command prompt I get ERROR: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3696: character  maps to . I know my code is encoded in utf-8, how do I make sure Windows can run this? Or is there a better way to set up a Bokeh server since I plan to implement this on a website?

Here is the slider/animate part of my code:

```
def animate_update():
    patchnum = slider.value + 0.1
    if patchnum > testdata['gameVersion'][slidelength]:
        patchnum = testdata['gameVersion'][0]
    slider.value = patchnum


def slider_update():
    truepatch = slider.value
    label.text = str(truepatch)
    newdata = testdata[testdata['gameVersion'] == truepatch].to_dict
    source.data = newdata

slider = Slider(start=testdata['gameVersion'][0], end=testdata['gameVersion']    [slidelength], value=testdata['gameVersion'][0], step=0.1, title='Patch')
slider.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: slider_update)

callback_id = None

def animate():
    global callback_id
    if button.label == '► Play':
        button.label = '❚❚ Pause'
        callback_id = curdoc().add_periodic_callback(animate_update, 200)
    else:
        button.label = '► Play'
        curdoc().remove_periodic_callback(callback_id)

button = Button(label='► Play', width=60)
button.on_click(animate)

layout = layout([
    [plot],
    [slider, button],
], sizing_mode='scale_width')

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = 'Playrate, Banrate and Winrate by Patch'
output_file('champminder.html')
show(layout)
```

Comment: Include the full traceback in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same problem some weeks ago when trying to use "bokeh serve ..." in a windows environment and with special characters (german umlauts).

The solution for me was, to run the server programmatically, like in this example:

- https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py
- [How to embed a bokeh server in a standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802159/how-to-embed-a-bokeh-server-in-a-standalone/51803389)

It seems to me, that "bokeh serve ..." is not handling the encoding correctly.

Comment: The examples work outside of Windows, it seems. The core devs are all linux/osx folks, so this is perhaps not a surprising oversight. If you work on windows regularly please consider helping to make Bokeh better on windows by directly contributing your expertise to the project.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I asked around and I figured out what was causing the issue. Turns out the icons next to the 'Play' and 'Pause' buttons were causing the problem, so I just deleted them and the code ran. There were still issues with the callback and slider update, but those were separate issues I managed to fix.